# Getting the estimated time of arrival between two geolocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, algorithm, api, google-maps

I'm writing a Rails backend for a mobile project and I've come across a pretty interesting problem.

I want to calculate the time of arrival between two points by car (with given points A and B) in what time A could arrive to point B. The reason why I do not take distance as a metric is because in terms of bird's eye view, the shortest distance doesn't always give you an accurate answer. Since traffic rules apply the vehicle A might be real close to point B but due to the available turns and etc. the vehicle C that is actually far more behind than the C could have a less time of arrival.

Of course using Google Maps API is the first and a pretty neat solution, however I consider that constantly querying the maps API could slow down the server, making my backend solution in efficient.

Would there be an alternative solution in order to provide an accurate time of arrival considering the real life complications such as turns, traffic and etc.

Comment: gmaps4rails contains a wrapper to query the google direction api: `Gmaps4rails.destination({ "from" => "", "to" => "" }, options={}, output="pretty")
`

Answer (score 0):

The directions service is included in the google maps API, just like geolocation.  IF you can use one, you can use the other.  From a google serach : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution.

Comment: I think this is the primary solution.  You want to consider a mountain of road data and traffic data.  Unless you have your own copy of something like that, you have to use a service.  In other words, No, there is no alternative.

Google has one that is intended to do exactly what you want.